# R: opposite of digest

Tags: r, md5, digest

Is there a function opposite of `digest` in R? I.e. if I create a hash and send it to another user - how can he/she decipher it? Using `md5` as method. Thanks!

Comment: They cannot. Hashes are meant to be one way.

Comment: Any method/function that can go both ways? This is not for crypto purposes, just a way to pass long strings in smaller "hashes" and decode on other end

Comment: Then what you want is compression. The algorithm depends on the data, but if it's not big then it's not worth it due to the overhead. You can't get much data into 128 bits even then